# $n\times n$ matrices whose entries are each 1 or -1 be such that the sum of the entries in each row and in each column is 0

Tags: permutations

> Find the number of $n\times n$ matrices whose entries are each 1 or -1 be such that the sum of the entries in each row and in each column is 0. ($n$ is given even)

I attempted this question in a way similar to an existing similar question about **multiplication** - [Number of ways of filling $n \times n$ binary matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2616180/number-of-ways-of-filling-n-times-n-matrix).

I tried a similar approach here. Fill the upper-left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix with 1 or -1 arbitrarily. But the problem here is that if a single row gets filled with more than $n/2$ $1$s, then it's impossible to put the sum zero for that row. Similar is the problem with the column.

So, I could instead start at a $(n-2)\times(n-2)$ matrix, but again, I'm not quite sure how that evades the problem.

So, what is the logic for the better method?

**Important note:** the original question had $n=4$, but I have attempted to post a generalized question here. Hopefully, that does not make the answer too complex. If it does, please post a solution for $4\times4$ instead. Though, I'll still be more than happy to reward an answer with a bounty, if they are able to solve the general $n\times n$ case.

---

I attempted to count by hand **for $4\times4$ matrices**, hopefully it gives the people an intuition to count the general case as well.

Let us first set two $1$s in the first row in $^4C_2$ ways. The second row has three cases of placing 1s:

1. both 1s below the first 1s - in only one way
2. one 1 below the first one - in four ways
3. neither of the 1s below the first row 1s - in only one way

Note that, in case 1, the rest of the matrix elements will be set *automatically* - to satisfy the property that the sum of the rows and the sum of columns is zero.

In case 2, for each way, we'll be able to fix *automatically* a few of the columns and rows, but four squares will be left - below the columns which have a 1 and -1 at their head. We have two more ways of placing 1s in those squares.

In case 3, only the first two rows are *automatically* fixed, and each columns would be similar to each other. So, wlog, choose the first column, place 1 and -1 below it in two ways. Similarly place 1 and -1 below the next one in two more ways. The remaining four squares are now *automatically* fixed.

This gives a total of $6\times(1\times1+4\times2+1\times2\times2)=78$ as the total number of ways. Unfortunately, **this is the wrong answer.** (acc my textbook) But, I've been unable to find the mistake here either.

Comment: My intuition here is that this will indeed add a lot of complexity. I would try solving the $6 \times 6$ case, and see if anything gets simpler, but I doubt it would.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for your input! I edited the question accordingly

Comment: This is the same as the number of $2m$-by-$2m$ matrices  with entries $0$ or $1$ with each row and column sum equal to $m$.  A more general problem is solved on pages 203-204 of Fulton, Young Tableaux, using the RSK correspondence.

Comment: In fact, an exact formula is available for the number  $m$-by-$n$ matrices with entries $0$ or $1$ with prescribed row and column sums .

Answer (score 3):

Given that $n$ must be even, it is clear that this question is equivalent to another one asked on Mathematics SE:

**"[How many ways are there to fill up a $2n x 2n matrix with 1, -1 so that each column and each row has n 1s and n -1s?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289381/how-many-ways-are-there-to-fill-up-a-2n-times-2n-matrix-with-1-1?noredirect=1&lq=1)**

In your case for a $4\times4$ matrix the answer is 90.
An explanation on how to derive this can be found at ["Number of 4×4 matrices with sum along row or column 0"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748658/number-of-4-times-4-matrices-with-sum-along-row-or-column-0?rq=1), and a different one at ["Number of ways to arrange signs in a grid"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529138/number-of-ways-to-arrange-signs-in-a-grid?rq=1)

The generalised problem is very difficult to solve, however, the method of enumerating them can be found ["Asymptotic Enumeration of Dense 0-1 Matrices withEqual Row Sums and Equal Column Sums"](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v12i1r29/pdf).

This question was also asked and answered on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151226/counting-2m-x-2m-0-1-matrices-with-m-ones-in-each-row-and-each-column).  For reasons of completeness and convenience, I have copied and collated the information that was given there.

As stated by others, this sequence can be found in [OEIS A058527](http://oeis.org/A058527) which lists the first 7 terms.

An explicit (closed) formula for this was published about 30 years ago, but it was wrong. As the matter stands, there is no explicit formula. The values up to $m=15$ can be found [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/semiregular.html), and the values relevant to this specific question are all those of the form $B(2m,m; 2m,m)$.

For convenience, I have listed them below.

$$\begin{align}
m=1. \quad & 2  \\
m=2. \quad & 90 \\
m=3. \quad & 297200 \\
m=4. \quad & 116963796250 \\
m=5. \quad & 6736218287430460752 \\
m=6. \quad & 64051375889927380035549804336 \\
m=7. \quad & 108738182111446498614705217754614976371200  \\ 
m=8. \quad & 34812290428176298285394893936773707951192224124239796250\\ 
m=9. \quad & 21882630320667689225357109687240364487595251549773\
48944382853301460850000
\end{align}$$

$m=10.$
27856726619148825494784078580561902698029561072477313921903857594739813713335069572835719440 ,

$m=11.$
73598361490497320315061303329860141625489297388873097402577973995078475595177219907273524251166598220695445665280 ,

$m=12.$
41166741168628144936713296088571382312319541605035039202139739426526710130553316487181153798718623434772470791046740497537457960747230000 ,

$m=13.$
4955718943988940005004146237479895414479770954795218135246063162883554097069851160345377950138482450273137136644609946481127918748277794634799510166778789400000000 ,

$m=14.$
130182965915524188822374132662598705148400755946368804279519820149265310510762181776582751351898520706779949869976891542842075030612982451615770950941110943399182350404672558394208550600000000 ,

$m=15.$
 755108153829514055973248475938007693494252921038915181695050280737084462727343843042892520013526446320417069829825720805149300044864243469236136642966675916041398513473858832514945641793476366441713887508829265486123827200 ,