# Number of $4 \times 4$ matrices with sum along row or column $0$

Tags: matrices, permutations

Find the number of $4 \times 4$ matrices whose entries are each $2018$ or $—2018$ such that the sum of the  entries in each row and in each column is $0$.

Now to get sum $0$ along a row we need two $2018$ and two $-2018$ and number of arrangement will be $\frac{4!}{2! 2!}$ but how adjust column while adjusting the rows or vice-versa? Could someone help me with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, we're after the number of $4 \times 4$ $(0,1)$-matrices $M=(m_{ij})$ with two $1$'s in each row and each column (and we can relabel the 0's to $2018$ and 1's to $-2018$).

There's 6 possible first rows, and they all complete to the same number of matrices, let's choose:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
? & ? & ? & ? \\
? & ? & ? & ? \\
? & ? & ? & ? \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The second row may be as shown in red below
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which uniquely completes (indicated in black above).  Or it may be as shown in red below
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 \\
? & ? & ? & ? \\
? & ? & ? & ? \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has six completions (determined by the third row):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Or it may be one of those shown in red below
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 \\
0 & ? & ? & 1 \\
0 & ? & ? & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 \\
0 & ? & 1 & ? \\
0 & ? & 1 & ? \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 \\
? & 0 & ? & 1 \\
? & 0 & ? & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 \\
? & 0 & 1 & ? \\
? & 0 & 1 & ? \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
(where I indicate some forced 0's and 1's in black) each of which have two completions, such as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}, \text{ and }
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 1 & \color{blue} 0 & \color{blue} 0 \\
\color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 & \color{red} 1 & \color{red} 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for the first example.

This gives
$$
6 \times (1+6+4 \times 2)=90
$$
matrices.

---

As a check, this is equal to the number of labeled $2$-regular subgraphs of $K_{4,4}$.  Unlabeled, there's only $C_8$ and $C_4 \cup C_4$, to which we apply the [Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_theorem) to enumerate the labeled cases, which gives:
$$
\frac{4!^2}{8}+\frac{4!^2}{32}=90
$$
since the bipartition-preserving automorphism groups of $C_8$ and $C_4 \cup C_4$ have sizes $8$ and $32$, respectively.

---

As another check, we can generate them using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
R:=Filtered(Tuples([0,1],4),r->Sum(r)=2); # legal rows
Q:=Filtered(Tuples(R,4),M->ForAll(TransposedMat(M),r->Sum(r)=2)); # legal matrices
```

and it we input `Size(Q);` we get `90`.